# Why javascript block from included template not executed in Djjango?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a javascript block in a template that is included into base.html. I wonder why it does not work?

Here's my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} Base {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
<script>
    console.log("print from base");
</script>
    {% block js %}
    {% endblock js %}
</html>
```

This is footer.html

```
{% block js %}
    <script>
        console.log("print from footer");
    </script>
{% endblock js %}
```

And here's index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
Content from index.html
{%endblock%}

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Only "Content from index.html" and "print from base" are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the reason for it. Found in Django docs.

The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process.

Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that have already been evaluated and rendered - not blocks that can be overridden by, for example, an extending template.